# Core data migration with renamed relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, mapping, core-data-migration

I have renamed an existing relationship from "bundleTopic" to "bundle" (both "bundleTopic" and "topic" are the same relationship, the change is to improve readability). However I'm not able to map the connection between the past model with "bundleTopic" as a relationship and the new version with "topic" as a relationship.

So far I've attempted:

1. Adding a value in the "Renaming ID" field for the relationship in
   the new version
2. In the mapping model, the "Key Path" field: `$source.bundleTopic` and the mapping name field" `QTQTopicToQTQTopic`. This gives a value expression of:

   FUNCTION($manager, "destinationInstancesForEntityMappingNamed:sourceInstances:" , "QTQTopicToQTQTopic", $source.bundleTopic)

However I get the following validation error for each "bundle" relationship:

```
Error migrating data: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1560 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1560.)" UserInfo=0x16996740 {NSDetailedErrors=(
    "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)\" UserInfo=0x169840f0 {NSValidationErrorObject=<NSManagedObject: 0x163b29f0> (entity: QTQBundle; id: 0x163b48d0 <x-coredata://F2CCE610-10AE-4910-A3B2-640200A74040/QTQBundle/p4> ; data: <fault>), NSValidationErrorKey=course, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)}",
```

Comment: show the PersistentStoreCoordinator and Migration code.